# Почему при загрузке html страницы отличается значение аргумента data-reactid у тега.?

Tags: html, python, request

Решаю учебную задачу и пытаюсь спарсить с [courser'ы](https://www.coursera.org/learn/stalinism) данные по курсу. На сайте почти у каждого тега есть атрибут data-reactid. Например:

```
<td class="td-data" data-reactid="155">10 weeks of study</td>
```

И вот такой код возвращает None:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('https://www.coursera.org/learn/stalinism')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'td-data', 'data-reactid': '155'}))
```

Как мне подсказали здесь, это происходит потому что при загрузке этот аргумент меняет значение. Объясните, что за data-reactid? Изначально data-reactid = 155, но при загрузке в request.text, data-reactid = 163. Почему так происходит?

На сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В response.text:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создайте минимальный но полный пример, кода который показывает проблему. Что по вашему "не так"? Что вы ожидали получить? Как это отличается от того что вы ожидали? [mcve]

Comment: @jfs добавил минимальный пример.

Comment: другими словами вы хотите спросить: как текст из элемента достать? (get_text())

Comment: На самом деле у меня получилось достать текст, хотел узнать почему через этот атрибут не получается, это же уникальный атрибут

Comment: вы понимаете что элемент (Tag) и текст внутри (str) это не одно и то же? Код в вопросе уже работает (находит элемент). Достаточно, вызвать get_text() метод на найденном элементе, чтобы текст получить.

Comment: @jfs почему тогда, когда я вызываю get_text() ошибка: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: *для теста* замените `request.text` на явную строку, вы увидите что элемент находится и не None.

Comment: @jfs И в чем тогда дело? type(request.text) = str, как преобразовать элемент внутри Tag в явную строку?

Comment: `html = '<td class="...>'` ("явная строка", константа, в исходном коде значение задано).  Подсказка: если soup.find работает с html указанным в вопросе, но не работает с response.text, то значит сайт что-то другое возвращает (не то что вы в вопросе показали).

Comment: Выгрузил в файл response.text, строка которую я показал в вопросе присутствует в нем

Comment: создайте полный пример кода с *минимальным* html куском прямо в коде, который показывает проблему (возвращает None).

Comment: @jfs с какой целью создавать минимальный html кусок внутри кода? Я пытаюсь спарсить этот html с сайта, который указан в примере.

Comment: чтобы продемонстрировать что find вызов работает. Отладка это пошаговый процесс. Это поможет локализировать проблему. Чтобы понять в какой части кода ошибка¶ Вы конечно можете ничего не делать (я дольше комментарии вам оставляю чем пример кода рабочий составить у меня заняло перед самым первым комментарием.) Следуйте инструкциям [mcve]

Comment: @jfs я не ленюсь создать, просто не понимаю какой именно кусок кода и куда нужно вставить. Если я вставлю чуть больше того что я уже показал, это особо ничего не даст. В любом случае, ваш комментарий принес плоды и я выяснил, что в response.text этот же самый элемент меняет react-id c 155 на 163. Приложил скриншоты

Comment: посмотрите на заголовок вашего вопроса: вопрос решён: find всё ищет. Теперь у вас новая проблема: значение data-reactid отличается. Почему значение атрибута разное уже никакого отношения к beautifulsoup не имеет. Новый вопрос задать или этот отредактировать, чтобы он отражал текущую проблему—это ваше дело.¶ В сторону: я не понимаю, что сложного в том, чтобы написать: `html = '<table>...<td..>...'; print(ascii(BeautifulSoup(html).find(...)))` чтобы убедиться что при ожидаемом html, find() всё находит.

Comment: @jfs, исправил. Сложного ничего нет, сразу не понял что вы имеете ввиду